# Why are Scandinavian countries promoting wearing masks so little compared to the rest of Europe?

Tags: covid-19, public-health

Living in a Scandinavian country, I have been surprised to see how little people wear masks, both in public transports (no more than 10% wear one there), supermarkets and offices. I know that the governments of these countries have been advising not to wear it, but surely governments' scientific advisors share similar sources of information regarding the efficiency of masks, so why are Scandinavian countries having different policies than the rest of Europe? ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Face_masks_during_the_COVID-19_pandemic?wprov=sfla1))

My personal opinion is that in general governments are reluctant to go back on their decisions which would make them appear weak, which would explain that Scandinavian governments didn't change their minds as data about the efficiency of masks accumulated as time went by after the beginning of the pandemic.
I'm aware that population density is quite small in Scandinavian compared to the rest of Europe, but the big cities are quite dense so it can't explain the difference of policies.

I noted that in some Scandinavian cities wearing a mask has been made  mandatory by the local transport companies, but it doesn't seem to change people's behavior.
Could it be because people have now been convinced about not wearing them at all?

I'm aware that my question is a bit of mix between politics and sociology, I hope this is the right place for it.

Comment: Isn't that peculiar to Sweden?

Comment: Related: [What political and social factors underlie Sweden's controversial response to COVID-19?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/52553/28994)

Comment: @Relaxed In the Wikipedia article that I link (and in particular the paragraph https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Face_masks_during_the_COVID-19_pandemic#Comparison_by_countries_and_territories), the percentage of people wearing masks is between 4 and 7 in all Scandinavian countries

Comment: Which countries specifically?

Comment: @CDA : The Wikipedia article says that the percentage of people wearing masks is 7% in Finland, 6% in Sweden, 5% in Norway and 4% in Denmark